# Ajax - PHP auto refresh looped data without relooping everything

Tags: php, ajax, database, while-loop, refresh

From the looped data I'd like to auto refresh only the data retrieved from the database, and not the whole layout. Currently I re-loop the complete layout but that seems somewhat clumsy (this table is a simplified example). Some direction or advice is appreciated!

```
<?
//.. rawdata.php ..//
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//building table by looping
?>
 <tr>
   <td><? echo $row['uniqueid']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $row['surname']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?
}
?>

<!-- index.php -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#loadRawData').load('rawdata.php');
    }, 5000);
</script>
<!--...-->
<div id="loadRawData"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only update or add records, you could add a “version” column to your table. Each time you update a row, or insert a new row, you increment the version and add it to the row.

You transmit the version to the client (it's a `MAX` on the *version* column). When the client does its “refresh” request, it sends you the version it had last downloaded, and you simply send the rows that verify a condition such as `WHERE version > clientVersion`.

It will be trickier if rows may be deleted, because in that case you will need to keep track of deleted rows in the table, in order to forward the “delete” operations to the clients. But you can manage them with the same “version” mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, still I would have to "reloop" the concerning layout. The actual layout is much more complex, and I would have to skip certain layout-structures, via additional constructs. I won't give up though :) thanks